# geom_smooth doesn't appear in scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a `geom_smooth` line in a `ggplot2` scatterplot but it doesn't appear when I add the function.

Here's a pasrt of my data frame `df`.

```
df <- structure(list(Kennisnamedatum = structure(c(17168, 17169, 17170, 
17171, 17172, 17173, 17174, 17175, 17176, 17177), class = "Date"), 
    misdrijven_per_dag = c(334L, 321L, 292L, 263L, 284L, 247L, 
    233L, 214L, 252L, 281L)), .Names = c("Kennisnamedatum", "misdrijven_per_dag"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Kennisnamedatum", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L), group_sizes = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), biggest_group_size = 1L, labels = structure(list(
    Kennisnamedatum = structure(c(17168, 17169, 17170, 17171, 
    17172, 17173, 17174, 17175, 17176, 17177), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Kennisnamedatum", drop = TRUE, .Names = "Kennisnamedatum"))
```

I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong by reading my plot code.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggiraph)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Kennisnamedatum, y = misdrijven_per_dag)) +
  geom_point_interactive(aes(tooltip = Kennisnamedatum,
                             data_id = Kennisnamedatum),
                         alpha = 0.6,
                         colour = "#607D8B" ) +
  geom_smooth() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month",
               date_labels = "%b")
```

I get this warning message: `geom_smooth() using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'`

[image]

Comment: Could you provide `dput(head(df))` instead?

Comment: what is the class for Kennisnamedatum?

Comment: The class of `Kennisnamedatum` is `date` also added some of the data.

Comment: No problem here using your data and `ggplot(df, aes(x = Kennisnamedatum, y = misdrijven_per_dag)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth() `

Comment: on my side, it does not work like you, but if run this `df <- data.frame(df)` before it works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `ggiraph`, so I did not test with `geom_point_interactive`. As mentionned by @Jimbou, if I use `geom_point`, I have no problem getting the graph, but with no interactivity.
I can give you an option with `plotly::ggplotly` to add the interactivity, using your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Kennisnamedatum, y = misdrijven_per_dag)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  geom_point(aes(text = Kennisnamedatum),
             alpha = 0.6,
             colour = "#607D8B") +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 day",
               date_labels = "%b %d")

ggplotly(plot, tooltip = "text")
```

Note that I have changed the scale for x so it would display something with the data you provided.